# Service worker in subdirectory, but I want scope to be root

Tags: javascript, firebase, service-worker

I am having service worker js in subdirectory (/data/system/) but I want it's scope to be from root directory. Following code:

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('/data/system/firebase-messaging-sw.js', { scope: '/' })
      .then(function(reg) {
        // registration worked
        console.log('Registration succeeded.');
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // registration failed
        console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
      });
    }
```

prints the error:

```
The path of the provided scope ('/') is not under the max scope allowed ('/data/system/'). Adjust the scope, move the Service Worker script, or use the Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header to allow the scope.
```

How do I extend the scope so it will work? How do I set set Service-Worker-Allowed HTTP header? I am having basic PHP application, no Angular, no React, nothing special. All the threads I searched were for those systems.

Comment: Maybe you already saw stackoverflow.com/questions/49084718/how-exactly-add-service-worker-allowed-to-register-service-worker-scope-in-upp ? They conclude moving the SW to root is best if at all possible:
"I guess there is not clear way to control that header to make service worker ... in a subfolder using html/javascript... It's a problem that could be solved only with server configurations...My conclusion is that not always it is possible to handle server configuration, so putting service worker file on root folder of the app is the best approach. Hope this could be helpful for some others"

Comment: Well the problem is, I have no control over the app. All I can do is to "inject" code to head / body, but I can not put worker in root in any means. So it has to stay in /data/system/ directory and as I can see, there is no way it would work this way. I am dissapointed. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I didn't read it all thoroughly, but that answer also implied that as long as the http request is not an ajax request, there is a way to set the header to make it work. Maybe you can still set this from the directory you have access to, I don't know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the answer is rather complex.

First, I noticed, that the code I provided earlier was registering service worker 2 times - first it was searching for root service worker, and second for the directory I specified. Problem lies in firebase itself, because it strictly search for root service worker. So I had to download firebase.js and re-work it so it search for my directory only. (for anyone curious in build 3.6.1-rc.3, line 525 in "navigator.serviceWorker.register" just change URL to yours desired) And use local copy of firebase instead of official one.

Second, I had to add .htaccess to the directory service worker is in with the following lines:

```
<Files "firebase-messaging-sw.js">
Header set Service-Worker-allowed "/"
</Files>
```

Just leaving this here for anyone else searching the same thing.